# Pandas: extract all regex matches from column, join with delimiter

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I need to extract all matches from a string in a column and populate a second column. The matches will be delimited by a comma.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1000, 'Jerry', 'string of text BR1001_BR1003_BR9009 more string','BR1003',''], 
                [1001, '', 'BR1010_BR1011 random text', 'BR1010',''], 
                ['', '', 'test to discardBR3009', 'BR2002',''],
                [1003, 'Perry','BR4009 pure gibberish','BR1001',''],
                [1004, 'Perry2','','BR1001','']],
               columns=['ID', 'Name', 'REGEX string', 'Member of','Status'])
```

Pattern representing the codes to be extracted.

```
BR_pat = re.compile(r'(BR[0-9]{4})', re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Hoped for output in column**

```
BR1001, BR1003, BR9009
BR1010,BR1011
BR3009
BR4009
```

My attempt:

```
df2['REGEX string'].str.extractall(BR_pat).unstack().fillna('').apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x))
```

Output:

```
 match
0  0        BR1001, BR1010, BR3009, BR4009
   1                    BR1003, BR1011, , 
   2                          BR9009, , ,
```

There are extra commas and rows missing. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```py
>>> df2['REGEX string'].str.findall(r'BR\d{4}').str.join(", ")
0    BR1001, BR1003, BR9009
1            BR1010, BR1011
2                    BR3009
3                    BR4009
4                          
Name: REGEX string, dtype: object
```

With [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html), you extract all occurrences of the pattern inside a string value, it returns a "*Series/Index of lists of strings*". To concatenate them into a single string, the [`Series.str.join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can also

1. add `axis=1` to `apply` to use columns instead of rows.
2. add `filter(None,x)` to filter out empty strings.

The result is

```
df['REGEX string'].str.extractall(BR_pat).unstack().fillna('').apply(lambda x : ",".join(filter(None,x)), axis=1)
```